# Unknown class PageContentViewController in Interface Builder file

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

Application build is successful, but when I start to run application, the program is stop and show this error

```
PageViewDemo[1355:8607] Unknown class PageContentViewController in Interface Builder file.
［UIViewController setImageFile:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance,
```

the interface is:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface PageContentViewController:UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *backgroundImageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property NSUInteger pageIndex;
@property NSString *titleText;
@property NSString *imageFile;
@end
```

Comment: Make sure the correct target is selected on PageContentVC. Some details such as screenshots of Xcode showing the class, the nib file, etc would be better.

Comment: @PhilippeA     #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

interface PageContentViewController:UIViewController
property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *backgroundImageView;
property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
property NSUInteger pageIndex;
property NSString *titleText;
property NSString *imageFile;
end

Comment: That's not what I meant. Open the .m file in Xcode, then in the right panel, open the File inspector, find the area titled Target Membership and verify that the target of your app is checked.

Comment: @PhilippeA thanks,the target already checked

Comment: OK. Try using the dot syntax to set the imageFile property: `myPageContentVC.imageFile = ...`